# Sort Months name Chronically in Descending order in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a very basic question in Power Bi I am trying to build a report in which I am using a Matrix Visual to display some data in the below format, However, I want the most recent months data to show first dynamically and then the following months after that, in this case show May first instead of Jan, Apr second instead of Feb and so on and so forth.

[image: Matrix Visual]

Comment: What is the source of your Month column? Is that String value? or you are picking Month name from a date value? If just Month name as string, do you have any corresponding Month number like 1,2,3..12 in your table?

Comment: I am Picking it from a date value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform these below steps to achieve your required output-

**Step 1:**
Add a new custom column "month_name" (if not already available) in Power Query as shown in the picture. Please use the Date column from your source go generate the new column.

[image]

**Step 2:**
Add another custom column "year_month" as shown in the below image. Remember the target is to get the value like - "202001" (YYYYMM) from the date value. You can achieve the same with other conversion option as well.  Please use the Date column from your source go generate the new column.

[image]

**Step 3:**
Change type of "year_month" column as Whole Number and get back to your report by clicking on the "Close & Apply" button.

**Step 4:**
Create a custom column "Rank" in the table as below-

[image]

**Step 5:**
Sort the "month_name" column using newly created column "rank" as shown in the below image-

[image]

**Step 6:**
Finally use the "month_name" column in your Matrix visual's column and this should be come up with your required output.

Comment: Hi I am getting the below error 

We Can't Sort the 'Month_Name' column by 'Rank'. There can't be more than one value in 'Rank' for the same value in 'Month_Name'. Please choose  a different column for sorting or update the data in 'Rank'.

Comment: Do you create the Month_name as custom column? in case of measure, you should face some issue.

Comment: No I have created it as custom column in the power query it self.

Comment: Ok, no issue there then. Please double check all steps again. It should work as I checked it here in my report and its working. On which step you are getting that error?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to sort matrix headers in power bi.
However there is a trick that you can apply in order to achieve this.

First Create a new column that referes your month column:

```
DescMonth = Table[Month]
```

Then create another column that keeps the order of the new column (you will need an ID Month column for this so be sure to create one if you haven't yet):

```
DescMonthOrder = - ( Table[IdMonth] )
```

Then sort the **DescMonth** column using the **DescMonthOrder** column

[image]

Finally use the **DescMonth** column in your matrix instead of the regular month column.
This way you will be able to achieve the following result:

[image]